# How to add a css class on click event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a class to a anchor tag when clicked. But, I am getting "add" undefined when I try to use `e.classList.add('active-link');` I'm trying to use the same method being used [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp).

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('#navbar__list li a');
links.forEach(function(e) {
    // e.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    //     e.preventDefault();
    //     for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    //     }
    // });

    e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // first remove active_link and active-section class from all a and section elements
        links.forEach(function(e) { 
            e.classList.remove('active-link');
            //console.log(`#section${e.id}`);
            //document.querySelector(`#section${e.id}`).classList.remove('active-section');
        })
        // add the active-class to the a element and active-section to the linked section
        e.classList.add('active-link');
       //document.querySelector(`#section${e.id}`).classList.add('active-section');
    })

});
```

Comment: `e` is an `Event` object, use `e.target`, [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) represents the element on which the `click` event was triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the problem because e.addEventListener('click', function(e) ) the e is event Object, you need to replace this :

````
e.classList.add('active-link');
```
By this
```
e.target.classList.add('active-link');
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your `e` variable name is confusing : depending on the scope it could have three different values. Try this :

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('#navbar__list li a');
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // first remove active_link and active-section class from all a and section elements
        links.forEach(function(l) { 
            l.classList.remove('active-link');
        })
        // add the active-class to the a element and active-section to the linked section
        link.classList.add('active-link');
    })

});
```